# What is wrong with my matrix multiplication code?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to multiply any two matrices (that have correct dimensions allowing it) in Python3 without using any imports except for math. (So no numpy).

That said, here is what I came up with:

```py
def dotMatrix(m1, m2):
    m1rows = len(m1[0])
    m1cols = len(m1)
    m2rows = len(m1[0])
    m2cols = len(m2)
    newcolumn = [0]*m2cols
    m = [newcolumn]*m2rows
    sum = 0

    for a in range(m1rows):
        for b in range(m2rows):
            for c in range(m2cols):
                sum += m1[a][c]*m2[c][b]

            m[a][b] = sum
            sum = 0

    return m


a = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
b = [[7,9,11],[8,10,12]]

c = dotMatrix(a,b)
print(c)
```

It is supposed to return `[[58,139],[64,154]]`, but instead it returns `[[54, 68], [54, 68]]`. Why is this?

I am working off of the example on [mathisfun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html)

Comment: You're experiencing the same problem as the duplicate when you do `newcolumn = [0]*m2cols`, followed by `m = [newcolumn]*m2rows`. Multiplying a `list` of `list`s makes multiple references to the *same* nested `list`.